# String instance behavior different than object

Tags: c#

string is an reference type (similar to object). Why the diff behavior in the following scenario - when creating an instance of string and object?

I understand the concept of immutability etc in string but that is to do with value assigned to string (which wont change). My question is more to do with why s2 is creating another complete instance whereas if i had done with object it doesnt do that?

[image]

Example of string

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s1 = "Hello";
        string s2 = s1;

        s1 = null;
        Console.WriteLine("s1 = " + s1);
        Console.WriteLine("s2 = " + s2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output: s2 still prints "Hello"

Example of object

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Name s1 = new Name();
        s1.id = 5;
        Name s2 = s1;

        s1 = null;
        Console.WriteLine("s1 = " + s1.id);
        Console.WriteLine("s2 = " + s2.id);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Name
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Output: Both s1 and s2 are null;

Comment: In the second code snippet, `s2` is not null but you can't see it because `s1.id` throws `NullReferenceException`. Remove `Console.WriteLine("s1 = " + s1.id);` and you will see `5` in the Console.

Comment: When you say something like `s1 = null` you are only setting that variable `s1` to null, you are not changing anything that `s1` used to refer to. And as @Selman22 said, if you remove the null ref exception, you'll see they both behave the same. Also, try actually running the code first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I'm sure you realize you are going to get a lot of `NullReferenceException` with that code you've got there.
Secondly, the string class is a fun and special `object` which you can mentally think of as a `primitive` data type. Let me just say though, `System.String` **is not a primitive type**.... but you can think about it like it is for general purposes.

I have drawn some diagrams that may better display what is going on in each of the examples you gave.

When you

```
string s1 = "Hello";
string s2 = s1;
```

An object named s1 of type string is created which points to a memory space that holds the value `"Hello"`. Then a new object of type string named s2 is created and the value of `"Hello"` from s1 is copied to another memory space and addressed by `s2`. This results in your memory looking as it does below.

[image]

Now, when you

```
s1 = null;
```

You have set the reference of `s1` to point to the `null pointer`, which leaves that memory with the value of "Hello" to float around until the garbage collector comes around and removes it. At this point `s1` is still pointing to the value that was copied earlier.

[image]

---

Now lets look at how this differs from a normal object.

When you

```
Name s1 = new Name();
s1.id = 5;
Name s2 = s1;
```

A memory space called `s1` is created which points to a newly allocated space in memory the large enough to hold the memory of a `Name` object.

Then you pointed to the memory space addressed in `s1` and changed its Property called `id` to be 5.

Then you created a new memory space called `s2` which copies the value of the address to the allocated memory mentioned above. So now `s1` and `s2` point to the same object in memory. This results in your memory looking as it does below.

[image]

**Note:** That at this point, if you were to change the value of `id` it would change for both `s1` and `s2`, and if that was nullable type you were using for `id`, and you set it to be `null`, the change would be reflected in both `s1` and `s2`.

Now if you were to

```
s1 = null;
```

as you did in your post. `s1` would change its address to point to the `null pointer`, and `s2` would continue to be looking at the same space in memory. Which results in what you see below.

[image]

---

Edit: To provide further explanation on why strings seem to behave like primitives and not like objects.
I don't know, however I will speculate.
My guess is that it was designed this way because developers want to use `string` as if it were a primitive. I will say that it is so nice to not have to worry about stray references to my string, or having to `clone` it before I make changes to it. However Microsoft could not make `string` a primitive type because strings are huge. The max length of a `string` is the maximum value of an `Int32`. And every letter is a `char` which is a `Int16`, so that is somewhere around 2 gigs I believe (don't quote my math). This means that strings are too big to store on the stack which is only 1MB. Thus strings have to be objects and placed on the heap.

If you are unaware of the differences between the stack and the heap, I do recommend looking it up, it is good to know how memory is handled, while in C# all that dirty work is done for you, if you decide to move to something like C++ you'll find yourself managing that on your own (not super fun).

So in short I suppose it is because we want to use strings like primitives, but they are implemented as objects because of the limitations of the stack.

Comment: Excellent Explanation with diagrams. Precisely what I was looking for. Just one question is even though strings are reference types - why do s1=s2 behave differently than o1=o2 ? Any particular reason why are they different

Comment: @Patrick You are certainly welcome, I have also edited my post to give my best answer to your question.

Comment: A good thing to look up is the term [Immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Strings are Immutable Objects, so if you attempt to modify one it gives you a new copy of the modified object back instead and leaves the original alone. This is what makes strings behave "like a primitive" because all primitives are immutable. In .NET 4.5 you can get the `System.Collections.Immutable` namespace [via NuGet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385366(v=vs.110).aspx), this lets you have objects like lists and dictionaries that behave that way too (modifying returns a new copy).

Comment: Indeed Immutable would be the thing to research, I didn't mention it because he stated in the OP he understood Immutables. However, that Immutable namespace looks pretty nice, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

In your second code snippet, `s2` is **not null** but you can't see it because `s1.id` throws `NullReferenceException` and you didn't *handle* it.So your program never reaches the second line.Remove it and you will  see `5` in the `Console`.After  `s1 = null;`, `s2` doesn't change.It is still pointing the `s1's` *old Location* in the memory.

Also if you don't want to remove the first line alternatively you can put it inside of `try/catch`  block:

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("s1 = " + s1.id);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
 Console.WriteLine("s2 = " + s2.id);
```

And you can see `5` in the `Console` and the exception message.But this is completely unnecessary; it will definitely throw exception because `s1` is **null**.So, as a result: *there is no difference between `string` and other reference types except `immutability`*

Answer (score 1):

Your variables are reference variables because they are declared with the `String` type. Your code is doing this:

1. Retrieve a reference to the string `Hello`
2. Assign that reference to the string variable `s1`
3. Create a new variable `s2` and assign its reference to the reference in `s1`
4. Assign `s1`'s reference to `null`

Throughout this process, the string `Hello` is still in memory and `s2` still references it. `s1` and `s2` are two different containers; they can each hold their own reference. Whether the reference is the same is immaterial.

I'll try a metaphor:

You (`s2`) and I (`s1`) are sitting in a room looking at a vase (`Hello`) on a table. This is akin to `s1` and `s2` pointing to the same string in memory, as they do after the second line in your `Main` method. Now, I get up and leave the room (`s1 = null;`) You're still looking at the vase, aren't you? We are two different people (variables) with the capacity to look at different things.